# Confused with references on pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, variable-assignment, memory-address

The task is to calculate the output of the following source code without a computer, which I would say is `"123 234 678 678"` because `ref1` is a reference on the value of `ptr` and in the moment where the address of `val2` is assigned to this pointer, then shouldn't `ref1` as well refer to its value?

```
int main() {
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    int val1 = 123, val2 {234};
    ptr = &val1;
    int& ref1 = *ptr;
    int& ref2 = val2;

    std::cout << ref1 << " ";
    std::cout << ref2 << " ";
    *ptr = 456; //ref1 = 456
    ptr = &val2; //*ptr = 234, why isn't ref1 as well equal to 234?
    *ptr = 678; //*ptr = 678, why isn't ref1 as well equal to 678?

    std::cout << ref1 << " ";
    std::cout << ref2 << "\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    //output: 123 234 456 678
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this declarations

```
int& ref1 = *ptr;
int& ref2 = val2;
```

`ref1` refers to `val1` and `ref2` refers to `val2`. After the declarations the references can not be changed to refer to other variables.

Pay attention to that the reference `ref1` does not refer to the pointer `ptr`. It refers the variable `val1` due to dereferencing the pointer that points to the variable `val1`.

So these statements

```
std::cout << ref1 << " ";
std::cout << ref2 << " ";
```

will output

```
121 234
```

In this statement

```
*ptr = 456;
```

the value of the variable `val1` is changed to `456` through using the pointer `ptr`.

After that the value of the pointer `ptr` was changed to store the address of the variable `val2`

```
ptr = &val2;
```

and the value of the variable `val2` was changed to `678` through using the pointer

```
*ptr = 678;
```

So these statements

```
std::cout << ref1 << " ";
std::cout << ref2 << "\n";
```

now will output

```
456 678
```

That is they output values of the variables to which the references refer to.

In this program the same one pointer was used to change values of two different objects due to reassignment of the pointer with addresses of the objects.